# Metaprogramming Ruby 2 example from the book isn't working when I try it. Trouble shooting assistance

Tags: ruby

While reading through a chapter of Metaprogramming Ruby 2, I've come across an example in the book that does not seem to work when I execute the code.

```
array_explorer.rb

def explore_array(method)
  code = "['a','b','c'].#{method}"
  puts "Evaluating: #{code}"
  eval code
end

loop { p explore_array(gets()) }
```

The code above is designed to illustrate the power of eval. In the next example the book teaches the major flaw of code injections and refactors the code like so to safeguard:

```
array_explorer.rb

def explore_array(method, *arguments)
  ['a','b','c'].send(method, *arguments)
end

loop { p explore_array(gets()) }
```

When I try to run the above code, the file always gives me this error no matter what array method I try to place in.

```
array_explorer.rb:2:in `explore_array': undefined method `:size (NoMethodError)
' for ["a", "b", "c"]:Array
```

I've tried taking out the `*arguments` portion to whittle it down. I tried using a string as input, a symbol as input, etc. This code doesn't work for some reason. Does anyone know why?

Comment: how are you invoking `array_explorer` in the second example?

Comment: Once again its Anthony to the rescue! Hey Anthony, I pretty much invoke it with this in the code loop { p explore_array(gets()) }. I'll add it in the edit, that's an important piece to the puzzle.

Comment: Once you execute the program, it'll activate a continuous loop until you enter a method that Array doesn't recognize. Well at least for the first example.

Comment: Happy belated birthday too! Anthony. Until my next sticking point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets` reads a line from `STDIN`; a "line" is defined as a string of characters ending with a newline (`\n`). Thus, you are trying to invoke the method `"size\n"`, which does not exist. Use `chomp` to get rid of the newline:

```
loop { p explore_array(gets.chomp) }
```

It does not matter in the first example, since you are evaluating the code `"['a', 'b', 'c'].size\n"`, which is still valid.

Comment: This was my mistake – the code in the book was supposed to work the way Dan tried to use it, but I broke it while editing the book's examples. This is one of the few examples that's not covered by automated tests in the book's build (because of the gets() and my own laziness). That's how it happened. :| I submitted an erratum for the next printing.